# Checking a Queue<T> Continuously

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I would like a function to check a Queue for new additions continuously on one thread

Obviously there is the option of a continuous loop with sleeps, but I want something less wasteful.

I considered a wait handle of some type and then having the queue signal it, but I can't override Enqueue safely as it is not virtual.

Now I'm considering encapsulating a `Queue<T>` as my best option but I wanted to ask you fine folks if there were a better one!

The idea is: I want many threads to access a socket connection while guaranteeing they read only the response for their message, so I was going to have one thread dispatch and read responses and then execute a callback with the response data (in plain text)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the blocking queue: [Creating a blocking Queue<T> in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net)

The basic idea is that when you call `TryDequeue` it will block until there is something in the queue. As you can see "beauty" of the blocking queue is that you don't have to poll/sleep or do anything crazy like that... it's the fundamental backbone for a Producer/Consumer pattern.

My version of the blocking queue is:

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> where T : class
{
    private bool closing;
    private readonly Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (queue)
            {
                return queue.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    public BlockingQueue()
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            closing = false;
            Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
        }
    }

    public bool Enqueue(T item)
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            if (closing || null == item)
            {
                return false;
            }

            queue.Enqueue(item);

            if (queue.Count == 1)
            {
                // wake up any blocked dequeue
                Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }


    public void Close()
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            if (!closing)
            {
                closing = true;
                queue.Clear();
                Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
            }
        }
    }


    public bool TryDequeue(out T value, int timeout = Timeout.Infinite)
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            while (queue.Count == 0)
            {
                if (closing || (timeout < Timeout.Infinite) || !Monitor.Wait(queue, timeout))
                {
                    value = default(T);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            value = queue.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            queue.Clear();
            Monitor.Pulse(queue);
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks to [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) for this one!

Comment: This implementation seems wrong to me. If I call `TryDequeue` on an empty queue with a finite timeout `t` it will return `default(T)` directly, no? It should wait at least `t` before giving up.

Comment: In TryDequeue(out T value, int timeout): timeout is an int, which matches what Monitor.Wait() expects, but Monitor.Wait() will throw a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException if a negative number is specified as timeout.
The second part of the if, which checks for a negative timeout, just ensures that a default value is returned instead of provoking an exception.